# How to send/receive broadcast between service and activity

Tags: android

I need to send message from `SmsReceiver` Class to My Main_Activity and can't do it. I tried out very much and searched But... .

### Here is my code

**SmsReceiver.java**

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    // Get the object of SmsManager
    final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        try {

            if (bundle != null) {

                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                    String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
                    Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: "+ senderNum + "; message: " + message);

                    Intent intent1=new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

                    intent1.putExtra("m",message);
                    context.sendBroadcast(intent1);
                } // end for loop
            } // bundle is null

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

        }

    }    
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
               final EditText intext=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2Inputtext);

          BroadcastReceiver mysms=new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                String sms=arg1.getExtras().getString("m");
                intext.setText(sms);

            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your code to send and register broadcast receiver not correct.
Send broadcast:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("your_action_name");
intent.putExtra(....);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

receive:

```
BroadcastReceiver mysms=new BroadcastReceiver() {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
          String sms=arg1.getExtras().getString("m");
          intext.setText(sms);

      }
};
registerReceiver(mysms, new IntentFilter("your_action_name"));
```

and remember to unregister when destroy your activity.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of  `context.sendBroadcast(intent1);` you should try  `context.startActivity(intent1);`

try this

```
Intent i = new Intent(context,Main.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(i);
```

Comment: sendBroadCast is for sending a broadcast intent. In your case u need to start an activity so you have call startActivity with your activity intent on the context.

Comment: It opens again main_Activity correctly, But doesn't show the sms text.

Comment: remember you are starting activity inside the loop, it might create problem. can u update your code

Comment: plus you dont need a broadcast recvr inside your actiivty it will never get called u r starting activity with data. try `getIntent().getExtras().getString("m");` inside onCreate of the activity

Comment: When I use `getIntent().getExtras().getString("m");` app don't run and gives this error `05-19 14:28:07.931: E/AndroidRuntime(8468):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-19 14:28:07.931: E/AndroidRuntime(8468): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-19 14:28:07.931: E/AndroidRuntime(8468):  at air.aiga.safecommunication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
05-19 14:28:07.931: E/AndroidRuntime(8468):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)'

Comment: I should say I don't want to open again Main_Activity when new sms received, I want to Update Main_Activity when new message received, Please Focus to this subject and I think that should use broadcastreceiver in Inner class extends broadcastReceiver in Main_Activity!

Comment: try chaning `getIntent().getExtras().getString("m");` to `getIntent().getStringExtra("m");`. you can try changing the launchMode of the activity to singleInstance or singleTask and modify intent flag accordingly. and process the new messages in onNewIntent. You achieve the same by using BroadCast receiver as well.

Comment: What should I add in  intent flag? I added "Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP" as Flag and i setted Launch Mode to "SingleTask" But Did not Work!