# Calling a method of an Activity from another thread

Tags: android, android-activity, intentservice

I am new to android. In my App, there are some Activities with listviews/ ExpandableListViews which are populated from relevant cursors. I also have an intentservice which syncs my App DB with a server on the net.

I want to call a method of the current foreground activity from the service which would update the list views. If my app is not running, it naturally should not call that method as the lists would by default show the updated data next time the app is started.

My question is,

1. How can I know whether my app is running?
2. How can I get the current foreground activity if my app is running?
3. How can I call the method if my activity is running?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: use BroadcastReciver in your activities. So you can send broadcast from your service and if an an activity is in foreground it catches that broadcast.

Answer (score 0):

You can know if the app is running with onResume, onStop, onCreate and so on...
Those function do just what you want...
Set new boolean variable "playing",
In the onCreate set the value true.
On the onResume set it too, and on onStop set to false.
Than when you need check it if it true or false.
Take a look here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

For your other question you can use brodcastReceiver and send brodcast, between the activity and the service.
[How to send/receive broadcast between service and activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23722097/how-to-send-receive-broadcast-between-service-and-activity)
Look at the question and the answer.
And you may also look at this tutorial:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html
I'm new on stackoverflow, tell me if I did something wrong...
I hope I helped! Good luck

Answer (score 0):

[EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) library is optimised for this kind of tasks, it simplifies the communication between components.